# Base64 encoding not working

Tags: java, base64, imaging

I'm using the following code to encode a `java.awt.Image` in Base64:

```
private String asBase64(Image image) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null),
            image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "PNG", out);
    byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();

    return Base64.encodeBytes(bytes);
}
```

But the returned String is somehow wrong: It seems to be too small (only 308 chars on a 20KB-file) and contains a big amount of repetitive characters in the middle (~200 `A` chars).

I did some debugging and found out that `bufferedImage` at least has correct dimensions, but `out` only contains 308 bytes after executing `ImageIO.write(...)`. This number increases with bigger images, but the characters keep being repetitive and too few.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm trying to use it in an html `img` tag, but nothing appears. I compared it to expected results using online converters, and it looks completely different. It's `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Base64`, but I tried with `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` and `com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Base64Encoder` as well, getting the exact same string, so I guess this one's working fine.

Comment: Well, of course like this: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,[encoded-string]">` (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML)

Comment: I didn't know that was possible, just learnt something. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as shown in the question creates an *empty* `BufferedImage`, and PNG format encodes empty images pretty effectively.

You probably intended it to contain a copy of the original image:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null),
        image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
graphics.drawImage( image, 0, 0, null);
graphics.dispose();
```

Comment: Oh dang, I completely missed that! That explains those repetative characters. I can't check it now, but I'm pretty sure that'll solve my problem, thank you.